# Remove a malicious link added automatically to my blog external links

Tags: blogger

My blog template adds a malicious link in `href` attribute when `href` is empty or not refer to any of my blog pages.

I have tried to search the script but I can't find where it's changing / adding the `href`.

---

my blog template source:
[**pastebin**](https://pastebin.com/ckMG1f0K)

```
<b:widget id='HTML10' locked='false' title='MenuNav' type='HTML' version='1'>
    <b:includable id='main'>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <nav class='header__nav' id='topnav' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement' role='navigation'>
            <button class='nav__toggle toggleClass reset' data-target='nav__menu'>
                <span class='nav__toggle--icon'><span/></span>
            </button>
            <data:content/>
        </nav><!-- .header__nav -->
    </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always search in your blog template code for external scripts that not belongs to a trusted party, usually all the inordinary behaviors happen by an external script that may injecting a malicious link or change the pages content,...etc. So avoid using free or hacked premium templates, and deal with a trusted template.

In your case I found the external script that causing the problem, search for:

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/tigakoin/them/e79bc2cc/heaadss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

remove it, and **Save Settings**.